# Fetch Data from multiple rows into one row

Tags: mysql, join, stored-procedures, inner-join

So, I have two tables,

In the first one I have some data that is co-related to the second table.

[image: The first table]
This is the structure of the first table.

Now the second table is as follows.

[image]

The first table has a list of questions which have  multiple values in the second table.

I wrote this query but it is not giving me the results which I want. Also I guess my query is not optimum.

```
SELECT a.programming_question_bank_id AS id, a.programming_question_bank_questions_text AS question, a.programming_questions_bank_skill_set AS skill_set, a.programming_questions_bank_topic_id AS topic_id, b.programming_test_i_o_input AS stdInput, b.programming_test_i_o_output AS stdOutput FROM (
SELECT programming_question_bank_id, programming_question_bank_questions_text, programming_questions_bank_skill_set, programming_questions_bank_topic_id
FROM client_trials.programming_test_question_bank WHERE programming_question_bank_id = 1)a
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT programming_test_i_o_question_id, programming_test_i_o_input, programming_test_i_o_output
FROM client_trials.programming_test_i_o WHERE programming_test_i_o_question_id = 1
)b ON a.programming_question_bank_id = b.programming_test_i_o_question_id
```

The output Which I am getting is as follows:

[image]

But I want the output something like this:

```
+----+---------------+-----------+----------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| id | question      | skill_set | topic_id | stdInput 1     | stdInput 2     | stdInput 3     | stdOutput 1     | stdInput 2      | stdInput 3      |
+----+---------------+-----------+----------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 1  | Test Question | java-1    | 1        | test 1 input 1 | test 1 input 2 | test 1 input 3 | test 1 output 1 | test 1 output 2 | test 1 output 3 |
+----+---------------+-----------+----------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Also, I wanted to write a Stored procedure, but I can't understand where to begin.

Any help is appreciated.

SQL for creating tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `programming_test_question_bank` (
  `programming_question_bank_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `creator_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `programming_question_bank_questions_text` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `programming_questions_bank_standard_input` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `programming_questions_bank_skill_set` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `programming_questions_bank_topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `programming_questions_bank_standard_output` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `programming_questions_bank_created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `programming_questions_bank_updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`programming_question_bank_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='All Programming questions should be added here'
```

```
CREATE TABLE `programming_test_i_o` (
  `programming_test_i_o_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `programming_test_i_o_question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `programming_test_i_o_input` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `programming_test_i_o_output` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `programming_test_i_o_created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `programming_test_i_o_updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`programming_test_i_o_id`),
  KEY `programming_test_i_o_FK` (`programming_test_i_o_question_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `programming_test_i_o_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`programming_test_i_o_question_id`) REFERENCES `programming_test_question_bank` (`programming_question_bank_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

INSERT STATEMENTS

```
INSERT INTO client_trials.programming_test_question_bank
(creator_id, programming_question_bank_questions_text, programming_questions_bank_standard_input, programming_questions_bank_skill_set, programming_questions_bank_topic_id, programming_questions_bank_standard_output, programming_questions_bank_created_at, programming_questions_bank_updated_at)
VALUES('1', 'Test Question - 1', '1,2', 'java-1', 1, '1,2', current_timestamp(), current_timestamp());


INSERT INTO client_trials.programming_test_i_o
(programming_test_i_o_question_id, programming_test_i_o_input, programming_test_i_o_output, programming_test_i_o_created_at, programming_test_i_o_updated_at)
VALUES(2, 'test 2 input 3', 'test 2 output 3', current_timestamp(), current_timestamp());
```

Comment: No images please. Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Questions like these are already answerd -> re/search [MySQL pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MySQL+pivot) or [MySQL convert records into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MySQL%20convert%20records%20into%20columns) on this website